# How to audit who changed the limit on a GDG (Generation Data Group)?

Tags: mainframe, zos

I have a situation where someone has changed the limit of a [GDG (Generation Data Group)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zosbasics/com.ibm.zos.zconcepts/zconcepts_175.htm) and I need to track down who made the change.  I know the command will be something like:

```
ALTER gdg-base LIMIT(xx)
```

Is this type of change audited by System Management Facility (SMF)? I took a cruise through the SMF manual but couldn’t find a hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [z/OS DFSMS Managing Catalogs
(SC23-6853-00)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idac100/smfeven.htm), SMF record type 66 records ALTER entries to the BCS. Of course, this assumes they are being recorded. On my system of record (an ADCD/ADLT-based z/OS system), they are being recorded by default.

61 (DEFINE) and 65 (DELETE) look useful as well.